# compare column to values from procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a list of values to evaluate. Example provided below

```
'16-%', '45-%','A1%','125%'
```

I then have 1 column that is the output of a stored procedure and 4 columns that get returned from aliased left outer joins

example :

```
Max(db_util.Efn_name_wid(tdl_tran.reason_code_id, 
               remit_rmc.remit_code_id, remit_rmc.remit_code_name, 'Reason')
) AS DEN_REASON

, Max(RMC_1.remit_code_name) 
       AS REMIT_CD1

,Max(RMC_2.remit_code_name) 
       AS REMIT_CD2

,Max(RMC_3.remit_code_name) 
       AS REMIT_CD3

,Max(RMC_4.remit_code_name) 
       AS REMIT_CD4
```

The logic I am trying to build is this:

IF DEN_REASON like (any value in the list)

THEN evaluate column remit_cd1 against the same list, if it matches any value in the list, then continue to remit_cd2,remit_cd3, remit_cd4 until it finds the first remit code that doesn't match the value in the list.

Ultimately trying to return one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this CASE statement might be what you need:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN DEN_REASON LIKE (/* your set of values */)
         AND REMIT_CD1 LIKE (/* your set of values */)
         AND REMIT_CD2 LIKE (/* your set of values */)
         AND REMIT_CD3 LIKE (/* your set of values */)
         AND REMIT_CD4 NOT LIKE (/* your set of values */)
         THEN REMIT_CD4
    WHEN DEN_REASON LIKE (/* your set of values */)
         AND REMIT_CD1 LIKE (/* your set of values */)
         AND REMIT_CD2 LIKE (/* your set of values */)
         AND REMIT_CD3 NOT LIKE (/* your set of values */)
         THEN REMIT_CD3
    WHEN DEN_REASON LIKE (/* your set of values */)
         AND REMIT_CD1 LIKE (/* your set of values */)
         AND REMIT_CD2 NOT LIKE (/* your set of values */)
         THEN REMIT_CD2
    WHEN DEN_REASON LIKE (/* your set of values */)
         AND REMIT_CD1 NOT LIKE (/* your set of values */)
         THEN REMIT_CD1
    WHEN DEN_REASON NOT LIKE (/* your set of values */)
         THEN DEN_REASON
    END AS YourSingleResult

FROM --your query
(   SELECT
    Max(db_util.Efn_name_wid(tdl_tran.reason_code_id, 
        remit_rmc.remit_code_id, remit_rmc.remit_code_name, 'Reason')
       ) AS DEN_REASON
    ,Max(RMC_1.remit_code_name) AS REMIT_CD1
    ,Max(RMC_2.remit_code_name) AS REMIT_CD2
    ,Max(RMC_3.remit_code_name) AS REMIT_CD3
    ,Max(RMC_4.remit_code_name) AS REMIT_CD4
    -- and the rest of your query, that you omitted from your example above
)
```

Then again, it might be shorter if you did your LIKE evals in your sub-query. Like this:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN MatchesDenReason = 1
         AND MatchesCD1 = 1
         AND MatchesCD2 = 1
         AND MatchesCD3 = 1
         AND MatchesCD4 = 0
         THEN REMIT_CD4
    WHEN MatchesDenReason = 1
         AND MatchesCD1 = 1
         AND MatchesCD2 = 1
         AND MatchesCD3 = 0
         THEN REMIT_CD3
    WHEN MatchesDenReason = 1
         AND MatchesCD1 = 1
         AND MatchesCD2 = 0
         THEN REMIT_CD2
    WHEN MatchesDenReason = 1
         AND MatchesCD1 = 0
         THEN REMIT_CD1
    WHEN MatchesDenReason = 0
         THEN DEN_REASON
    END AS YourSingleResult

FROM --your query
(   SELECT
    Max(db_util.Efn_name_wid(tdl_tran.reason_code_id, 
        remit_rmc.remit_code_id, remit_rmc.remit_code_name, 'Reason')
       ) AS DEN_REASON
    ,CASE WHEN Max(db_util.Efn_name_wid(tdl_tran.reason_code_id, 
        remit_rmc.remit_code_id, remit_rmc.remit_code_name, 'Reason')
       ) LIKE (/* your list */) 
          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MatchesDenReason
    ,Max(RMC_1.remit_code_name) AS REMIT_CD1
    ,CASE WHEN Max(RMC_1.remit_code_name) LIKE (/* your list */) 
          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MatchesCD1
    ,Max(RMC_2.remit_code_name) AS REMIT_CD2
    ,CASE WHEN Max(RMC_2.remit_code_name) LIKE (/* your list */) 
          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MatchesCD2
    ,Max(RMC_3.remit_code_name) AS REMIT_CD3
    ,CASE WHEN Max(RMC_3.remit_code_name) LIKE (/* your list */) 
          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MatchesCD3
    ,Max(RMC_4.remit_code_name) AS REMIT_CD4
    ,CASE WHEN Max(RMC_4.remit_code_name) LIKE (/* your list */) 
          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MatchesCD4
    -- and the rest of your query, that you omitted from your example above
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Forgive me for not posting this as a solution